# Identity in Lattices

Tags: logic, order-theory

I'm having trouble proving this identity found in Curry's Foundations of Mathematical Logic.

Let $L$ be a lattice. For all $a,b,c,d \in L$, show that:
$$(a \wedge b) \vee (c \wedge d) \leq (a \vee c) \wedge (b \vee d)  $$

I've tried to first show: 
$$a \wedge b \leq (a \vee c) \wedge (b \vee d)$$
$$ c \wedge d \leq (a \vee c) \wedge (b \vee d)$$
but I'm getting nowhere.

Is this a good approach, or should I try something different?
Should I try finding a counter-example?

Answer (score 3):

$$a\land b\le a\le a\lor c$$
$$a\land b\le b\le b\lor d$$
$$a\land b\le a\lor c\quad\&\quad a\land b\le b\lor d\implies a\land b\le(a\lor c)\land(b\lor d)$$

Comment: Thank you @bof!